# CSS behavior item for tag for FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-2008

I have CSS that look like

```
.ajax
{
    display: block;
    behavior: url(/file.htc);
}
```

file.htc containe some JS code :( this stuff works just in IE (http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/behavior#compatibilitysection) Is it possible to make it work in FF and Chrome ?

Comment: What is the [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) you're trying to solve?

Comment: You'd have to re-implement the behavior with JavaScript somehow. Perhaps the existing code would be a good starting point but it'd end up being somewhat different. Of course, once you did that, the new code might work for IE anyway.

Comment: I think FF and Chrome can already do *that* without implementing behavior :)

Comment: Inside of this file.htc some JS that works(calling) just insede IE. Other browsers don't know about it. I need to make it work for all browsers.

Comment: @cleric — You **can't**; see Pointy's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htc` componentes can be only used on Internet Explorer.

As far as I know, there's a similar functionality only for [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-binding) using [Extensible Bindings Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XBL) that you can use to attach your own behaviours to a DOM element through  `-moz-binding` CSS property.

Note that, since we are talking about two different languages, you will need to rewrite your behaviour from scracth if you're planning to use it also on firefox. So try to consider a totally different approach (e.g. using only javascript)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's IE only feature. Use regular javascript for other browsers. You actually need it mostly for older versions of IE since they didn't support some of the CSS.

As you could see in the link you provided it's only compatible with IE.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome and Firefox etc you can use CSS3, HTML5 and javascript, simply faster and more efficient.